# Trying to install latest LTS onto my Thinkpad X250

Tags: boot, usb, uefi

Bottom line up front: Very capable "tech person" stumped by trying to install Ubuntu onto an X250.

Overview: I recently purchased a Thinkpad X250 from Backmarket (a refurbished electronics website).

Specifics:
UEFI BIOS version: N10ET36W (1.15) from 2015-06-19
Intel Core i7-5600 @ 2.6GHz
8192MB of RAM
256GB SSD

When I received the device and powered it on, a version of Windows was loaded that was suspicious (and I had planned on installing Ubuntu anyway). So I powered down the device and inserted my USB install media for Ubuntu and attempted to install. The installation process completed successfully, I rebooted the system and powered it back on, and... nothing.

These issues are usually b/c of BIOS/UEFI settings, so I accessed that menu and began to dig.

None of my usual tricks are working. I've turned secure boot on and off, switched between UEFI only, Legacy only, and both (with legacy first), I've switched between the apparently two different versions of TPM available on the device (between discrete TPM and Intel PTT), I've enabled and disabled OS optimized defaults...

I've attempted to update the BIOS from USB, even. With all the same result. The laptop isn't reading from USB. The indicator light on the USB flashes a few times, and then nothing happens. This same pattern occurs when I insert a W10 install USB, a W8 install USB, and the Ubuntu USB.

Please, someone fix (me) and (this computer).

Thank you

Comment: I bought a PC from off market too and had to wipe the Hard Drive completely with a "Live" GParted CD. I'm not sure what kinda spyware or whatever they have....

Comment: https://www.prosofteng.com/support/mediatoolswipe/changing-your-pcs-boot-device-priority/